# How to find ID of selected option in HTML select?

Tags: javascript

I want to find the ID of the selected option in my HTMl select element. But in console I keep seeing an empty line, not undefined nor an error. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```js
  var getSelect = document.querySelectorAll('.custom-select');
  
  getSelect.forEach(function(option) {
  option.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    var target = e.target.id;
    console.log(target);
  })
 });
```

```html
  <select class="custom-select" name="category">
  <option id="option-1" class="cat-option" value="Coronavirus">Coronavirus</option>
  <option id="option-2" class="cat-option" value="Reserveren">Reserveren</option>
  <option id="option-3" class="cat-option" value="Prijzen en toeslagen">Prijzen en toeslagen</option>
  <option id="option-4" class="cat-option" value="Speciale wensen en extra's">Speciale wensen en extra's</option>
  <option id="option-5" class="cat-option" value="Betalen">Betalen</option>
  <option id="option-6" class="cat-option" value="Wijzigen of annuleren">Wijzigen of annuleren</option>
  <option id="option-7" class="cat-option" value="Buitenland">Buitenland</option>
  <option id="option-8" class="cat-option" value="Air Miles">Air Miles</option>
  <option id="option-9" class="cat-option" value="Na uw verblijf">Na uw verblijf</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: Had you just logged `e.target` first, you would have seen that this is the `select` element itself …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with `e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].id`

```js
  var getSelect = document.querySelectorAll('.custom-select');
  
  getSelect.forEach(function(option) {
  option.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    var target = e.target.id;
    console.log(e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].id);
  })
 });
```

```html
  <select class="custom-select" name="category">
  <option id="option-1" class="cat-option" value="Coronavirus">Coronavirus</option>
  <option id="option-2" class="cat-option" value="Reserveren">Reserveren</option>
  <option id="option-3" class="cat-option" value="Prijzen en toeslagen">Prijzen en toeslagen</option>
  <option id="option-4" class="cat-option" value="Speciale wensen en extra's">Speciale wensen en extra's</option>
  <option id="option-5" class="cat-option" value="Betalen">Betalen</option>
  <option id="option-6" class="cat-option" value="Wijzigen of annuleren">Wijzigen of annuleren</option>
  <option id="option-7" class="cat-option" value="Buitenland">Buitenland</option>
  <option id="option-8" class="cat-option" value="Air Miles">Air Miles</option>
  <option id="option-9" class="cat-option" value="Na uw verblijf">Na uw verblijf</option>
  </select>
```